# Connecting MySQL remote url to spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to my remote MySQL database which is on the server, in my application.properties I have following config

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://www.mydomain.com:3306/my_database_name
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
```

But i get this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure remote connection is enabled on MySQL server ( Try connecting from workbench or other sql client from your local machine with above username and password  to test if remote connection is active. Activate if not active
2. Make sure port 3306 is open on server ( in firewall of server)
3. Make sure domain is getting resolved correctly ( ping www.my_domain.com